# Android : Persisting object(s) between BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that receives SMS and starts certain "work", now this work is done through Camera and some other third party APIs.  So when I receive the appropriate START message (SMS) for my app, I start the work and it continues till the app receives STOP message from remote device.

The receiver is registered in the manifest.xml file and works fine otherwise.

Now the problem is, my app starts the work fine on receiving the START message, but when I receive STOP message after some time, I cannot really stop the work because the handles/object references I have for the camera and the third party API both are null. I do not have any control over either of them - and can't make them singleton. So I need to persist those object references between two calls of the `BroadcastReceiver`, and I can't figure out a way to do this properly. For now, I have just made these two static members of the class and it works fine, but it's not really a good solution. What's the best way to handle situation in this case? How can I use the initialized objects between multiple `onReceive()` calls of the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated!

TIA,
- Manish

Answer (score 1):

You can't use singleton that class, but you can create a normal class and have it singleton. That class has a HashMap and stores your api and camera objects with a key. When you need to stop particular task, you can find it by some key and stops them by that object.

When you start the task store that object in that singleton and when you want to stop that find that object from the hashmap and stops/dispose the task.

I suggest you to create a singleton object volatile.

```
private static volatile Utils _instance = null;


public static Utils Instance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        synchronized (Utils.class) {
            _instance = new Utils();
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

Comment: Let me try this. Sounds reasonable

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the object reference in the `ApplicationClass` i.e. a class extended from `Application` class. your application class persist in memory until any `Activity` or `Service` is running. It will only killed after all the `Activity` and `Service` killed.

I think this is a better approach that Static field.
But this is also not **Full-Proof**. I am also searching for this problem.

Comment: I don't have access to 'Application' from 'BroadcastReceiver', there is no activity here.